# Issue about text and content slipping from the block. It has done with CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

ISSUE IMAGE:
[![image of the problem][1]][1]
content is shifting how can I solve this problem.
This slipping problem is very common in the tablet, what kind of solution do I need and where I make mistakes. I would be glad if you help. I could not find a solution.

SOLVED

Comment: CSS Columns is meant to create columns within text elements and does not care where to break a column. So you're using the wrong tools for the job. Look into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), it will probably work better for your case.

Comment: can you do those in flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent an item from being split in a css column using `break-inside: avoid;` ([See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside)) on your three cards class `.anasayfakutular`

Comment: How can i do them in a sort in 3 columns?